# Kotlin how to make a ViewBinding by viewBindings() similar to ViewModel by viewModels()

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

In Kotlin there is this nice extension function that allows us to write

```
var viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
```

Is it possible to have the same thing for ViewBindings?
Currently I am using this (in Activities):

```
var viewBinding: MyViewBinding by lazy { MyViewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }
```

It works but feels a bit clumsy. I'd rather have it like the following but do not know how to implement that:

```
var viewBinding: MyViewBinding by viewBindings()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure you can write a property delegate for a viewbinding for any class that holds views. You can check out [this library](https://github.com/androidbroadcast/ViewBindingPropertyDelegate) for inspiration, or even use it in your project